# How to show Text at top right corner of Action bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using Action bar at top of my app Where i have setTitle to tht which is shown left corner of ActionBar Now I want to show Some Text To right most corner of the ActionBar instead of subTitle

[image]

like highlighted in Red want to show some Static Text at right
How can i do this?

Comment: use custom layout for actionbar

Comment: having it works ????

Comment: @DigveshPatel yes its working fine Thnks for help

Comment: always welcome btw great to see your image gallery ..... salute your passion.

Comment: @DigveshPatel thnks for appreciation

Comment: not appreciation its duty if some 1 doing a great thing than suporting tham

Comment: Don't both with the AppBar it's junk. Make a custom AppBar will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");



        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }

}





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/black_pattern" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:tex="356"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

create custom action bar as @Digvesh Patel says .
refer below link for do that .
http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android